# Problem in generating a GNU screen session with Ruby in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: scripts, screen, vnc, ruby, gnu

I have a workstation with Ubuntu 20.04 installed where I'm facing problem in generating GNU screen session inside a ruby script. The Ruby script has to generate a new GNU screen session with a custom name and attach the new session to a VNC server process.

Here is the code.

[image: Here is the code]

After creating a folder where copying the screen_rc configuration and storing the GNU screen log, a new screen session is generated with logging (-L), a custom name (-S), detached mode (-d), skipping STY env variable (-m). I introduced some debug messages (for example, screen ls command), which show me no generated sessions after the command is issued.

This behavior is quite strange because the same Ruby script works perfectly in the previous Ubuntu version (16.04 and 18.04).
I noticed that the GNU screen version differs between these distributions:

Ubuntu 16.04: 4.03.01
Ubuntu 18.04: 4.06.02
Ubuntu 20.04: 4.08.00

Also immediately after rebooting the workstation, the script works, but just for the first run. It seems that something remains pending, but there are no pending processes.

I found a temporary workaround downgrading the screen version to the 4.03.01 (Ubuntu 16.04), making the script working also in Ubuntu 20.04, but I would like to solve the problem with the newer version of GNU screen for the full porting of the script on the latest version of Ubuntu.